# easy way to change a dict data to url Parameter 

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url, parameters

(1)

```
a={'b':'bbbb','c':'ccc',....}
```

(2)

```
self.redirect('/tribes/view?b=' + a['b'] + '&c=' + a['c'])
```

so i want to get

```
b=' + a['b'] + '&c=' + a['c'] ...
```

from dict a

hae any easy way to do this  ?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from urllib import urlencode
urlencode({'b':'bbbb', 'c':'ccc'})
```